# Implicit conversion between template type

Tags: c++, templates

I created two types : `bool_t` and `number_t` and I wanted to convert one into another (in the two ways). However, I got some issues to convert the `bool_t` into a `number_t`.

Basically what I want to do is that (but it does not compile) :

```cpp
template<bool v>
struct bool_t {
    template<template<int> typename T>
    operator T<v ? 1 : 0>() {
        return {};
    }
};

template<int N>
struct number_t {
template<int n1, int n2>
friend number_t<n1 + n2> operator+(number_t<n1>, number_t<n2>) {
  return {};
}
};


int main() {
    number_t<0>{} + bool_t<0>{};   
}
```

and the error is :

```
prog.cc:19:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('number_t<0>' and 'bool_t<0>')
    number_t<0>{} + bool_t<0>{};   
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:12:26: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'number_t' against 'bool_t'
friend number_t<n1 + n2> operator+(number_t<n1>, number_t<n2>) {
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't have both a user-defined conversion for and template argument deduction from the same function argument.

Comment: So the only way to solve this problem is to use function like `bool_to_number` ?

Comment: Or maybe a bunch more `operator+` definitions. But also, if I define `template <int> class Thing;`, you really want `bool_t<true>{}` to implicitly convert to `Thing<1>{}` without knowing any more about it?

Comment: The issue is that it will be mandatory to add a lot of `operator` functions ahaha ^^.
No ! It is only for example, but i wanted to protect it with sfinae or static_assert ;)

Comment: Ah, okay. So in reality there are a limited variety of `number_t`-like templates, and you need to be able to process a `bool_t` type like any of them?

Comment: It is globally that yes. I only have the number_t and the bool_t that I want to be able to convert to a number_t for example counting values in an array that respect a predicat :)

Comment: If that's the only conversion, why a template conversion operator, rather than just `template<bool v> struct bool_t { operator number_t<v ? 1 : 0>() const; };`? There may be some other reasonable solutions, depending on what types of generalization are actually needed.

Comment: It does not compile also : https://wandbox.org/permlink/jJMPX51yrcI2etsY . I think I should go with writing function for both number and bool ^^...

Comment: Oh right, that wouldn't help the core issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User-defined conversions are never considered when attempting to match up function argument types with function parameter types for template argument deduction.  So this issue is a somewhat more complicated version of this sort of error:

```
template <int> struct X {};
struct Y {
    operator X<2> () const { return {}; }
};
template <int N>
void f(X<N>) {}

int main()
{
    Y y;
    f(y); // Error: Cannot deduce template argument.
}
```

Since it seems you're making something along the lines of a template meta-programming library, perhaps you could define a custom mechanism for converting types in your library "to a template"?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<bool v>
struct bool_t {
    // (Add some appropriate SFINAE.)
    template<template<int> typename T>
    constexpr T<v ? 1 : 0> convert_template() const {
        return {};
    }
};

template<typename T, template<int> class TT>
struct type_specializes : std::false_type {};

template<template<int> class TT, int N>
struct type_specializes<TT<N>, TT> : std::true_type {};

template<int N>
struct number_t {
    // Allow "conversion" to my own template:
    template<template<int> typename T>
    constexpr std::enable_if_t<type_specializes<number_t, T>::value, number_t>
    convert_template() const { return {}; }

private:
    // Used only in decltype; no definition needed.
    template<int n1, int n2>
    static number_t<n1 + n2> sum_impl(number_t<n1>, number_t<n2>);

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    friend auto operator+(T1&& x, T2&& y)
        -> decltype(number_t::sum_impl(
             x.template convert_template<number_t>(),
             y.template convert_template<number_t>()))
    { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    number_t<0>{} + bool_t<0>{};   
}
```

If you want to allow both operands to be `bool_t` specializations, the `operator+` will need to be a proper visible namespace member; you can add more SFINAE checks to it if appropriate.

Comment: I really like this approach. However, since you are using friend with full templated operator +, it is not dangerous for other types, right? (because of ADL)?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier ADL will limit it to expressions where some `number_t<N>` is an associated class of an argument, yes. But it's also doing SFINAE: Since the return type is essentially `decltype(sum_impl(...))`, this `operator+` will only produce a candidate if both arguments have a `convert_template` member template.  (And maybe I should have used `number_t::sum_impl`, to avoid ADL on `sum_impl` there.)

Comment: Are you sure that SFINAE works under this condition? (I mean without decltype)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Oops, SFINAE does NOT work on a placeholder return type. (I had done a test, but made a mistake.)  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#11 "Any errors that arise from this instantiation are not in the context of the function type and can result in the program being ill-formed."

Comment: Fixed the example.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue boils down to that the language allows at most one implicit conversion.

One solution would then be to make a function accepting bool_t as well:

```
number_t<n1 + n2> operator+(number_t<n1>, bool_t<n2>) {
  //return something
}
```